# Rails - where to put data files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, path, location, raw-data

I wonder where to put data files (for example XML) to be loaded internally by Rails?
Is there some standard location? Now I hold the file in "public" folder.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think that depends on which kind of data you have in your files. If the files are supposed to be loaded at startup, perhaps the `config` folder would be good. If they are needed for some backend processing, `lib` could be the place. Or just create a `data` folder.

There's a table at the end of section 3.2 [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-a-new-rails-project) with the default folders and their intended purpose.

Comment: I'm thinking lib will be better than data folder, because most likely the custom files will be manipulated with rake tasks, which itself is in lib.

Answer (score 9):

The public folder is for public content.

You can create a folder "data" at the root of your app without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Copying the answer from *Hyrme* from this thread:
[Where to store static data for Rails app? : rails](https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/3stx28/where_to_store_static_data_for_rails_app/)

> You have multiple choices depending on what the data is used for. Keep it under
>
> - `db/data`
> - or create a new folder called `data/` under the project
> - or if this is configuration information keep it under `config/data`